# How to get the TFS Server Version Programmatically?

Tags: c#

Is there any API exposed by TFS to find out which version of TFS is installed?
Or can anyone tell me how to find TFS Server installed programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to `IBuildServer` interface in order to resolve server's version
Firstly instanciate `TeamFoundationServer` object
call service with `IBuildServer` type, and print `BuildServerVersion` property

for 2010 you must have v3

for 2012 you must have v4

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver.buildserverversion(v=vs.100).aspx

> Here you have full sample

sample : http://nigelonagile.com/2010/09/08/173/

Comment: Thanks for the help. how will i differentiate between TFS 2012 and TFS 2013. Both are giving V4.